# Woodstox stax and java stax conflict

Tags: java, stax, woodstox

I'm facing a weird runtime conflict between Woodstox STAX and java 1.6 STAX implementation. Since I'm using CXF,its pulling Woodstox jar as part of its dependency. Here's a sample code I'm using.

```
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute;
import javax.xml.stream.events.EndElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

XMLInputFactory factory = (XMLInputFactory)XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLEventReader reader =
factory.createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(xml)); 
while (reader.hasNext()){
XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
switch (event.getEventType()){
case XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT :
StartElement se = event.asStartElement();
...........
...........
case XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT :
EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
if (event.asEndElement().getName().getLocalPart()==("document"))
// do something
```

During runtime, I'm getting the following exception.

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ctc.wstx.evt.CompactStartElement cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.events.EndElement
```

when it reaches line `EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();`

I'm sort of puzzled why its causing at this point though it doesn't fail in 
`StartElement se = event.asStartElement();`

While debugging, I found that the event objects are part of com.ctc.wstx.evt package and not javax.xml.stream. But not sure why its not failing before.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve dis problem?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have two possible choices from a superficial view:

1. Use a dependency exclusion to turn off Woodstox. CXF works with the built-in StaX -- give or take the various bugs in the built-in Stax.
2. Use Woodstox yourself.

However, the specific error here is a bit unlikely. I mostly recommend posting this to the cxf users list, and telling us there exactly what version of CXF you are using.

Comment: Thanks bmargulies .. I was also thinking of using the woodstox objects directy, but was not able to find documentation / example which will provide some info...

Comment: Just use the factories in the Woodstox package. Their javadoc has them.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the exception, it says basically that one can not cast StartElement to EndElement; it does not seem like an incompatibility between stax implementations but rather a bug somewhere. Which Woodstox version is this?

Answer (score 1):

A `break` at the end of `XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT` case should not be missing here otherwise it will just going to continue to the `END_ELEMENT` case with the first START_ELEMENT event, hence the ClassCastException.

That part of the code have been omitted from the question so I thought I would put this here just in case this simple error might have been overlooked. It's how I got the same exception that led me here anyway when I realised I needed a break ;)