# Java XMLInputFactory Error

Tags: java, eclipse, xml-parsing, stax

I have some code like:

```
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
```

...

```
XMLInputFactory xmlin = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()
```

which has been written in Eclipse.

This code produces an error like:

```
Caught: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
```

Which I can't work out at the moment. I suspect it's something to do with a library clash (similar to [Woodstox stax and java stax conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019969/woodstox-stax-and-java-stax-conflict)) but I'm not sure if that's correct, or how to resolve it.

If anyone can point me in a direction to start understanding this behaviour that would be great!

Thanks,
Arlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is to do with the build path. I had an old version of Stax-api being picked up somewhere.